# Does oberdiek bundle actually contain ifpdf package?

Tags: packages, miktex

From the installation chapter of [the `ifpdf` documentation](ftp://ftp.ctan.org/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/ifpdf.pdf), it sounds like having the `oberdiek` package means you have the `ifpdf` package.  When I use the MiKTeX 2.9 package manager, `oberdiek` shows up as installed but `ifpdf` does not show up at all. The `ifpdf` package is not listed at [the CTAN page for `oberdiek`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/oberdiek), but it is listed at [the MiKTeX package page for `oberdiek`](http://miktex.org/packages/oberdiek).  Obviously, I trust the latter more since I'm using MiKTeX, but it sure would be reassuring if `ifpdf` showed up explicitly.  Is there a way to double check its presence?

This message has been posted as the following threads.
http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=24134

Comment: [`ifpdf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ifpdf) *is* listed under the [`oberdiek` bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/oberdiek) on CTAN: http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek

Comment: The documentation to `ifpdf` also says it is a part of the Oberdiek bundle.  The question is what MikTeX does, I suppose, and I can't answer that.

Comment: `ifpdf.sty` is in the miktex package "oberdiek" (you can check the file list in the properties) and is installed by miktex in `tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty`. And if you want to check its presence use findtexmf on the command line - or simply typeset a small document which loads it.

Comment: `ifpdf.sty` _is_ in the `ctan.org` catalogue web page for the `oberdiek` bundle, but the formatting of the page is so dire that no-one would blame you for not noticing it.  the `xml` sources that i write contain formatting hints, and they _are_ preserved in the old-style catalogue formatting (at http://mirror.ctan.org/help/Catalogue/entries/oberdiek.html)

Answer (score 1):

The CTAN page contains a link to oberdiek.pdf which lists ifpdf. The webpage itself doesn't *seem* to (at least not from my case-insensitive search).  I also couldn't find it from searching the source code for the page (AFTERNOTE: This is because it shows up as if-pdf in Microsoft Internet Exporer!).  I would have found it if I looked in oberdiek.pdf, but I probably would have been confused by the disparity between the webpage summary and the document.  So thanks for clearing that up, as well as for pointers on how to check for its presence.  In particular, from web searching, the findtexmf command seems to be specific to MiKTeX and one needs to know th file to look for.  This can be found in the ifpdf documentation under Section 4.3 (Package Installation).

I was hesitant to actually rely on loading the package as a test because I'm not too sure what kind of measures LaTeX resorts to in order to avoid crashing when it doesn't find a package.  I suppose "nothing" is the right answer.

The thread at http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=24134 also suggests "texdoc oberdiek".  I issued this at the DOS command line, which made it abundantly clear that ifpdf is present.

Thanks, all.

AFTERNOTE: Because of the browser wrinkle in searching for package names, described above, one really needs to delve into the PDF documentation.  Unless you are guaranteed to be alway using a browser that is immune the problem described.